# JAVA PhantomJS not working

Tags: java, phantomjs

I'm trying to get the html source of [Zhaopin Login Page](https://passport.zhaopin.com/org/login) with HttpResponse (and HttpClient), Jsoup and HtmlUnit (first tried it worked) but i haven't successed. The three methods return me obfuscated html source (and with the three of them i tried sending all the headers).

So i tried with PhantomJS, because i red that it waits for the page's javascript to execute, but i'm also having no success.

Has someone used it?

Here is the method i use:

```
public static Document renderPage(String url) {
    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "/usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs");
    WebDriver ghostDriver = new PhantomJSDriver();
    try {
        ghostDriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(-1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        ghostDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(-1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        ghostDriver.get(url);
        return Jsoup.parse(ghostDriver.getPageSource());
    } finally {
        ghostDriver.quit();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This produces the source of the page (at least here with the lastest SNAPSHOT from HtmlUnit). The page code still contains a lot of javascript stuff but it should be easy to move this out.

```
    try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://passport.zhaopin.com/org/login");
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

        System.out.println(page.asXml());
    }
```